# how to stop a thread in Android?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm using a Thread to initialize some resources while displaying a splash screen with a progress bar, and sometimes start a different activity (for result).

At first I used AsyncTask, which works great, except that I found out that I can't use another one(Android 1.5) so I had to use a Thread.

currently, my code looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    m_progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    m_progressBar.setMax(10);
    // start the Init process
    Thread thread = new Thread(initTask);
    thread.start();
```

As Thread.stop() is deprecated, and I can't use Thread.interrupt(), If I press the back key, I can't stop the thread from starting a new Activity.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the source of the code that is running in the thread?

Answer (score 1):

Stopping a thread requires the cooperation from the thread in question. The general idea is to send the thread a signal, and it regularly checks for that signal and then stops itself. The simplest "signal" is a simple boolean field that it checks.

Comment: I removed the bit about using a looper thread, because that wouldn't work in your situation. If the quit method is called while a work item is in progress, it won't stop the thread until the work has finished. So you still have to have some sort of signaling mechanism

Comment: how can I signal a thread in the middle of its running method?

Comment: You have a boolean field somewhere that is initially set to false, and then you set it to true when you want the thread to stop. In the running thread, it periodically checks if the value is true, and if so, it stops itself (i.e. return from of the Thread.run() method)

Comment: Blocking methods (like `stream.read()`) can be interrupted with `Thread.interrupt()` : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use multiple `AsyncTasks` at the same time, there is no limit on that. What was the problem?

**Update:** Indeed before 1.6 AsyncTasks were executed serially on same background thread, one after another.

Second, threading in java is cooperative - you can not kill a thread, but rather you have to notify it about your intent to be stopped and it then stops it itself (i.e. exits the run method).

To signal it to stop, just have a boolean field running=true which thread checks in it's main loop. When running==false thread exits the run() method.

Comment: The way he worded the question, it sounded like a known limitation on 1.5. I don't know either way myself.

Comment: In android 1.5 I can use only 1 AsyncTask at a time.
I looking for a better solution than a boolean, because the Thread's work isn't in a loop, and further more I'll need to add synchronization

Comment: Just checked - there are two methods added in API 11: `execute(runnable)` and `onCanceled()`. Neither is essential.

Comment: @piojo - ahh, yes. Before 1.6 AT were execute serially, one after another.

Comment: A side note: there is only 1.0% of devices out there with OS 1.5 and 1.8% devices with OS 1.6. I only target 2.1 and above.

Comment: You don't need to add synchronization to check a boolean field used in this manner. The worst thing that will happen is that you get the updated value slightly later, so the thread runs for slightly longer than necessary.

Comment: and it starts the activity, and now its too late